# Display result of GET method in a form

Tags: php, forms

I'm trying to retain the query string in the URL so that the result of a search query can be bookmarked.  The appropriate content displays in the body when I previously used the "Post" action for the form, but when I switch to "get", the content does not render, but the query string appears in the URL.  How can I do both? Thanks for your help on this folks!

```
        <body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="content">
<h1>Search for a book</h1>
 <p>You  may search by author or title</p> 
        <form  method="GET" action=""  > 
          <input  type="text" name="search"> 
          <input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Search"> 
        </form> 
        <br />

<?php 


$conn = new COM("ADODB.Connection") or die("Cannot start ADO");

$connString= "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=e:\\assignment3.mdb";

//creates the connection object and define the connection string



$conn->Open($connString);
$searchquery = $_GET ('search');
$selectCommand="SELECT * FROM AuthorTitle WHERE  title LIKE '%$searchquery%' OR author LIKE '%$searchquery%'";

if(isset($_GET['search'])){
$rs = $conn->Execute($selectCommand);

//opens a recordset from the connection object


if (!$rs->EOF){

$selectCommand=$rs->Fields("ProductID");
$author=$rs->Fields("author");
$title=$rs->Fields("title");

echo "<h1>Search Result for '<b>$searchquery</b>':</h1>
<p><b>$title</b>, $author is available for checkout.</p><br />";

}

else

print "No results found.<br /><br />";



$rs->Close;
}
?>



</div> <!--end content-->
</div> <!--end wrapper-->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$_GET ('search')` => `$_GET['search']`?

Comment: `$_GET` isn't a function, it's a [superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

`$searchquery = $_GET ('search');`

To:

`$searchquery = $_GET['search'];`

Comment: Yeah, the same, about 15 seconds sooner :P

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
$searchquery = $_GET ('search');
```

To:

```
$searchquery = $_GET['search'];
```

Comment: Snap! Photo finish! haha